# Cloning one of the Database in AWS RDS in order to get a test DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-cloning

I am quiet new to AWS and trying to learn things. I currently have a live production environment and trying to create a test environment. I was able to create an image of an ec2 instance in AWS using the 'Create Image' option in the 'Actions'. Now I am trying to create an image/ duplicate of the RDS Database in AWS in a similar way. Is there any easy way to clone the database so that I don't change any data in the original database and perform modifications only in the test database. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably worth reading up on [creating snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html) and [restoring from a snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html).

To give you a quick summary; you will take a snapshot of your production RDS DB instance.  Then you will launch a new DB instance from this snapshot.

As long as you don't need to launch the new instance in a separate AWS Account, the documentation should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to create the duplicate DB from the original DB Instance. For connecting this duplicate DB, except the end-point(DB_host), would everything be the same as that of the original instance(I mean DB _name, DB_username, DB_Password )?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can specify those values when you launch the new DB instance from the snapshot.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Was able to successfully do the changes.

Comment: Excellent.  Now I know this sounds like I'm rep hunting... but if you found the answer useful don't forget to accept it (tick) and up-vote it.  This helps others in the community who are facing the same problem as you :)